# Symfony2.3: unmapped fields missing in Form Event

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Two unmapped hidden fields have been added to a Form Type to enable data modification in a PRE_SUBMIT Form Event.  The fields and their data, however, are not available in the Form Event as observed in Netbeans debug.  There is a third unmapped field that is available.  Testing has shown that being hidden fields is not the reason the fields do not appear in the Event.  The hidden fields are properly rendered in the form.  Curiously, when using

```
$form->getErrorsAsString();
```

in the controller the fields appear in the string of form errors (as having no errors).

#### Form class:

```
class HouseholdType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('active', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array('1' => 'Yes', '0' => 'No'),
                'data' => 1,
            ))
            ->add('addresses', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new AddressType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'prototype' => true,
                'prototype_name' => '__address__',
            ))
            ->add('arrivalmonth', new Type\MonthType(), array(
                'empty_value' => false,
                'data' => date('n'),
            ))
            ->add('arrivalyear', new Type\YearType(), array(
                'empty_value' => false,
            ))
            ->add('foodStamps', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array('0' => 'No', '1' => 'Yes', '2' => 'Appl.'),
                'empty_value' => false,
            ))
            //this field appears at Form Event
            ->add('isHead', 'choice', array(
                'expanded' => true,
                'mapped' => false,
                    )
            )
            //the following two fields do not appear in Form Event
            ->add('headId', 'hidden', array(
                'mapped' => false,
            ))
            ->add('v1Date', 'hidden', array(
                'mapped' => false,
            ))
            ->add('members', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new MemberType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'prototype' => true,
            ))
            ->add('wic', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array('0' => 'No', '1' => 'Yes', '2' => 'Appl.'),
                'empty_value' => false,
            ))
    ;

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
                $data = $event->getData();
                $event->setData($data);
            });
}
```

Comment: The problem is tunnel vision, in this case neglecting to properly name a manually included field.  The template needed to refer to the form name as well as the field!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When manually including a field in a template, use formname[fieldname].  For example, the unmapped hidden field isHead should read:
`<input type="hidden" name="household[isHead]"...`